# Showing static social media timeline posts using ListView in Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin

I want to display something like social media timeline posts [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29185.jpg) Here is my ListView Code which is currently due to some mistake not showing anything.

```
<StackLayout>

<ListView x:Name="LvTimeLine">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>

  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>

      <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="0.15" />
              <RowDefinition Height="0.35" />
              <RowDefinition Height="0.20" />
              <RowDefinition Height="0.10" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.50" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

      <Image x:Name="Imagedp" Source="{Binding ProfilePic}" HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="70" />

      </BoxView>

      <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">

       <Label Text="{Binding ProfileName}" />

      </BoxView>

      <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">

              <!--post image-->
          <Image x:Name="ImagePostImage" Source="{Binding PostImage}" HeightRequest="250" />

      </BoxView>

      <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">

              <!--Details-->
          <Label Text="{Binding PostDesc}" />


      </BoxView>


      <BoxView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">

              <!--Category-->
          <Label Text="{Binding PostCat}" />


      </BoxView>

      <BoxView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3">

              <!--Like button-->
          <Label Text="Like - Comment - Share" />


      </BoxView>




      </Grid>


    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>

</ListView.ItemTemplate>  
</ListView>


</StackLayout>
```

Here is my class PostList.cs which I am binding in my listview.

```
    public class PostList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProfilePic { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public string PostImage { get; set; }

    public string PostDesc { get; set; }
    public string PostCat { get; set; }

}
```

Also I have declared 3 records to show on my listview

```
    public TabActiveForms()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LvTimeLine.ItemsSource = new List<PostList>
        {
            new PostList() { Id=1, ProfileName = "Uzair", ProfilePic = "D1.jpg", PostCat = "Sports", PostDesc = "Lahore Stadium", PostImage = "P1.jpg"},
            new PostList() { Id=2, ProfileName = "Tasmeer", ProfilePic = "D2.jpg", PostCat = "Sports", PostDesc = "Karachi Stadium", PostImage = "P2.jpg"},
            new PostList() { Id=3, ProfileName = "Aamna", ProfilePic = "D3.jpg", PostCat = "Home", PostDesc = "Talagang Stadium", PostImage = "P3.JPG"},
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `ObservableCollection<PostList>` instead of `List<PostList>`

Second, your Model should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

I suggest to use [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) for INPC

Answer (score 0):

For a **static** (as stated in the question title) listview collection, there is no strict requirement to use `ObservableCollection`. It is perfectly fine to use a normal `List` or `array` as long as the content is static. An `ObservableCollection` makes sure your `ListView` gets notifications whenever the collection changes. The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface makes sure your `ViewCell` can respond to changes in the object itself. See the Xamarin documentation on [ListView ItemsSource](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/#ItemsSource).

Changing `List` to `ObservableCollection` won't help you a lot in your case, as you have some other fundamental issues in the code you provided.

1. The Row and Column Definitions are most likely not what you want, your definitions result in a very small grid. Xamarin works with `*`, `Auto` or absolute values. Refer to [the documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/#Rows_and_Columns) for more information.
2. The BoxViews don't add anything, they are likely the reason you are not seeing anything. [`BoxView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BoxView/) does not support child elements as it is not a `ContentView` but a regular `View`.
3. You should set the `HasUnevenRows` property of the `ListView` to true, or set a fixed cell height that fits the size you want.
4. For some odd reason that I can't explain yet, I had to override the `ToString()` method for the Bindings to work.

Although `ObservableCollection` probably won't fix your issue, it is worth to know how it works, and make use of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. I can also recommend the `PropertyChanged` package base on Fody as Alessandro mentioned.